# Entity Framework cannot evaluate expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

If i execute this part of the code:

```
var adressenDetailses = new KlippsTestEntities().AdressenDetails.Count();
```

the variable `adressenDetailses` has the value 961. (That means the enumeration has values)

If I want to check the values of the `IEnumerable` `AdressenDetails` during debugging then Visual Studio says

> 'For the functionevalution all threads have to be executed'.

I execute the Thread by clicking the reload icon. Now Visual Studio says:

> 'The expression can not be evaluated. The process is not supported.
>   Unknown error: 0x80070057.'

Does anyone knows the answer to how I can fix the problem?

Comment: You are trying to view KlippsTestEntities.AdressenDetails in VS debugger?

Comment: Is `AdressenDetails` a table in your database? Which _specific_ methods within a `AdressenDetail` object in your IEnumerable can't be viewed? Ignore my answer until you answer this please.

Comment: @AndyWiesendanger yes thats exactly my problem, if i add a .ToList() to my IEnumerable then i can see results the debugging window.

Comment: @gunr2171 AdressenDetails is in the DataBase. I can load this information. I get values for all IEnumerable functions, who iterates throw the enumeration.

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework is lazy.

I mean this is a good way. It will only fetch the data it *needs* to fetch up-front. Any linking values - like links/FKs to other tables - will get only when it is asked.

This is why you are are seeing this behavior when you are *debugging*, but if you wrote the full code out and ran it normally it would produce the correct values.

You can enable "eager loading" using an `Include` line

```
var adressenDetailses = new KlippsTestEntities()
    .Include(x => x.AdressenDetails) //tells EF to eager load that link
    .Select(x=> x.AdressenDetails); //"I would only like to see data on the details"

var addressCount = adressenDetailses.Count();
```

Now you should be able to debug the first line and see the specific details of that object.

Side note: you don't need to add the `.Select(x=> x.AdressenDetails);` clause.